# Blender 2.8: export 3d object to use as website (wordpress) background

Tags: 3d-view, export

I'm totally new in Blender, I'm even not sure if what I want to do is possible:

I want a website where the main structure is a 3d staircase. So I use blender to create this:
[image]

Now I would like to export it and use it in my (wordpress) website background. Does someone know if this is possible and how?

I did see that there is a wordpress plugin especialy for 3d objects, but this plugin is mainly so you can rotate the object on the website, which is not what I'm looking for..

Hope someone knows more about this than I do :)